# How can I save output tho the same file that I have got the data from, in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to open a file, remove some characters (defined in dic) and then save it to the same the file.
I can print the output and it looks fine, but I cannot save it into the same file that the original text is being loaded from.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import sys
import fileinput

dic = {'/':' ', '{3}':''};


def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Example")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.load_file, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    def load_file(self):
        fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Napisy", "*.txt"),
                                           ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if fname:
            try:
                with open (fname, 'r+') as myfile: #here
                    data = myfile.read()           #here
                    data2 = replace_all(data, dic) #here
                    print(data2)                   #here
                    data.write(data2)              #and here should it happen

            except:
                showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read file\n'%s'" % fname)
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

I have tried several commands but either I am receiving python errors or it is simply not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings do not have a .write method.  The following should work (I tried it): replace

```
data.write(data2)              #and here should it happen
```

with

```
myfile.seek(0)
myfile.truncate()
myfile.write(data2)
```

The truncate() call is needed if data2 is shorter than data as otherwise, the tail end of data will be left in the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is often implemented by writing to a temp file and then moving it to the original file's name.